# How to customize UWP DataGrid from MyToolkit?

Tags: c#, uwp, datagrid

I'm building a UWP Application and I need to divide a DataGrid in four equal parts like this:

[image: colored grid]

But nothing worked so far to set the color of cells. Is there any way to do this Programatically in C#?

**EDIT:**

After a lot of research, I ended developing from scratch using Grid, a bunch of Labels + Borders and a virtual TextBox. The final result was pretty good actually:
[image: colored grid]

Comment: Yeah my personal favorite way to do this is not bother with MS built in types... Just write it in C# code yourself- saves so many headaches and hacks. Just my personal way of doing things for work if I can’t get an answer in a reasonable time.

Comment: I think that probably will be the best choice. But I'm already having headaches thinking about the 'edition'. The table must be editable.

Comment: Textboxes are editable... Have a bunch of those in a grid.. btw I wouldn't do this by hand- Id write some code to smartly generate the cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an easy way to get your requirement. You just need to define the DataTemplate for `DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate` and bind the background to some one property in your custom class.

Please see my following simple code sample:

```
<controls:DataGrid
AutoGenerateColumns="False"
ItemsSource="{Binding tests}" GridLinesVisibility="All">
        <controls:DataGrid.Columns>
            <!-- Name Column -->
            <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name">
                <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  Background="{Binding Color1}">
                            <TextBlock
                        Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name">
                <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  Background="{Binding Color1}">
                            <TextBlock
                        Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name">
                <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  Background="{Binding Color1}">
                            <TextBlock
                        Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name">
                <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  Background="{Binding Color2}">
                            <TextBlock
                        Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name">
                <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  Background="{Binding Color2}">
                            <TextBlock
                        Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name">
                <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  Background="{Binding Color2}">
                            <TextBlock
                        Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </controls:DataGrid.Columns>
    </controls:DataGrid>
```

```cs
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public ObservableCollection<Test> tests { get; set; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        tests = new ObservableCollection<Test>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {
            if (i < 7)
            {
                tests.Add(new Test() { Name = "Name " + i, Color1 = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow), Color2 = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red) });
            }
            else
            {
                tests.Add(new Test() { Name = "Name " + i, Color1 = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green), Color2 = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue) });
            }
        }
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public SolidColorBrush Color1 { get; set; }
    public SolidColorBrush Color2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The size (columns and rows) of the table are variable. So I can't define static columns in the XAML. Is there a way to do this programatically?

Comment: @alurab If it's auto-generated datagrid, it's impossible at the monent. Please submit a **Feature Request** on [Windows Community Toolkit Issues](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+label%3A%22feature+request%22).

Comment: Actually I feed the DataGrid with DataTable + ObservableCollection at runtime. Still impossible?

Comment: @alurab Yes. If you cannot use my above way(using `DataGridTemplateColumn` and `CellTemplate`) to show your data, there's no other way to achieve your target at the moment. Please submit a Feature Request on [Windows Community Toolkit Issues](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+label%3A%22feature+request%22).